# Why can I totally misspell the tags of the deserialization classes in xml file with Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I am using Jackson to deserialize a xml file:

```
public SomeClassDTO deserializeXML(String pathToFile) {
    File file = new File(pathToFile);
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    String xml = null;
    try {
        xml = inputStreamToString(new FileInputStream(file));
        xml = xml.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
        logger.error("file could not be found");
    }
    SomeClassDTO value = new SomeClassDTO();
    try {
        value = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, SomeClassDTO.class);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException jsonProcessingException) {
        logger.error("Deserialization failed");
        jsonProcessingException.printStackTrace();
    }
    return value;
}

public String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        logger.error("Die Konfigurationsdatei kann nicht gelesen werden.");
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Furthermore this is how the SomeClassDTO looks as followed:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SomeClassDTO {
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }
}
```

And this how the Book class looks like:

```
class Book {
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

And this the xml file which I try to read:

```
<SomeClassDTO>
<books>
    <Boosdfsk>
        <name>sldjfks</name>
    </Boosdfsk>
    <Book>
        <name>blablub</name>
    </Book>
</books>
</SomeClassDTO>
```

As you can see, it is completely unnecessary if I write "Book" or "Booksdhfsj" or whatever.
This fact really confuses me.

Comment: As far as i know there is a configuration/property called "deserialization-fail-on-unknown-properties" or something similar which is false by default meaning if during deserialization it meets a property it can't map (like Boosdfsk) it will just ignore them instead of thowing an error. So the result of your deserialization should be the same as if you would remove the wrong `<Boosdfsk>` tag.

Comment: If founde the code snippet `xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);` unfortunately it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Jackson has enough information about the deserialized type by inspecting the `books` property, it doesn't need to know anything about the tag used for each child object.  It knows every child element will be a `Book`.

You can see related conversation in this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/322

In short, any annotations you use to configure the tag name used for `Book` would only be used for serialization.

If you wanted to *only* read `Book`s, one option would be to create a class `Books` which reads the list of books as an [*unwrapped* list](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/wiki/Jackson-XML-annotations#jacksonxmlelementwrapper).